# Error in running tesseract OCR on Linux for .jpg

Tags: amazon-ec2, ocr, tesseract

I sucessfully installed tesseract on my Amazon EC2 instance following [this guide](http://alangunning.ie/2013/01/13/how-to-install-tesseract-ocr-on-a-amazon-ec2-free-tier-linux-machine-for-optical-character-recognition/). It works fine for TIFF images but when I try to run it on a JPG I get:

```
Tesseract Open Source OCR Engine v3.02.02 with Leptonica
Error in pixReadStreamJpeg: function not present
Error in pixReadStream: jpeg: no pix returned
Error in pixRead: pix not read
Unsupported image type.
```

What else do I need to install/do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem I had to manually install all the image-libs then reinstall leptonica

First install this

```
sudo apt-get install libjpeg-dev libpng-dev libtiff4-dev
```

Then reinstall leptonica

```
./configure && make && sudo make install
```

Comment: On CentOS 6.7, even with `libpng-devel` installed, after reinstalling `leptonica`, `tesseract -v` will still missing `libpng` support.

Comment: I gas ti recompile tesseract too.

Answer (score 4):

I got the same issue as well. It is due to your leptonica installation might have some issue. Try re-install leptonica again:

```
$tar -xvf leptonica-xx.tar.gz
$cd leptonica folder
$./configure
$make
$sudo make install
```

Once done, you can check all the lib is properly installed by:

```
$tesseract -v
```

Then it will show the 4 libs that are installed:

```
tesseract 3.02.02
leptonica-1.71
libjpeg 6b : libpng 1.2.49 : libtiff 3.9.4 : zlib 1.2.3
```

Cheers :)